# decompressing API response in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compression, httparty

Using the httparty gem, in CLI mode

```
httparty -a post -H Content-Type:application/json -H Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate "https://test.co.uk/search" -d '{ "requestAuditInfo ": { "agentCode ": "001 ", "requestPassword ": "PASSWORD", "requestDateTime ": "2018-08-03T23:52:31Z ", "requestID ": 1 },[...]'
```

the post command returns, in the above case, as well as if `-H Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate` is **omitted**:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [GZipCompressionFilter]: Could not find required filter class - uk.co.controller.filter.GZipCompressionFilter.class
```

When run from the application controller action (again, as well as if `-H Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate` is **omitted**), response has slightly more articulated information (sensitive data scrubbed, breaks for legibility purpose):

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x7fd4ebc81988 parsed_response="Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [GZipCompressionFilter]: Could not find required filter class - uk.co.controller.filter.GZipCompressionFilter.class\n", 
@response=#<Net::HTTPInternalServerError 500 Internal Server Error readbody=true>, 
@headers={"date"=>["Sat, 04 Aug 2018 00:08:28 GMT"], 
"content-type"=>["text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"], 
"transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"], 
"connection"=>["keep-alive"], 
"set-cookie"=>["__cfduid=d5331e829a3bf88ad6c8eb42f8d697d071533341308; expires=Sun, 04-Aug-19 00:08:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.co.uk; HttpOnly"], 
"$wsep"=>[""], "content-language"=>["en-US"], "x-powered-by"=>["Servlet/3.0"], 
"expect-ct"=>["max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""], 
"server"=>["cloudflare"], "cf-ray"=>["444cca2c29834352-MXP"]}>
```

The API was **not** experiencing this error a few hours ago.

This indicates that the API is the one with the compression issue - is that correct?  Or, *as the service has prefers to serve responses compressed*, am I not handling a *forced* gzipped response properly?